# Window hanging on call to new thread

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am having a WPF MVVM application where in the first screen is a log-in screen and once log-in successful it is opening the MainWindow. so once enter button is clicked my log-in screen is getting hanged.I am using a dispatcher thread to open the mainwindow as it takes some 8-10 secs to load the application.  Here is my code:

code for Log-in screen Enter button:

```
private ICommand _EnterCommand;
public ICommand EnterCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _EnterCommand ?? (_EnterCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            Thread objThread = new Thread(LoadApplication);
            objThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            objThread.Start();

        }));
    }
}
```

code to open Main Window on a thread (here show progress is to show the busy indicator):

```
    public void LoadApplication()
    {
        ShowProgress = true;
        if (isAuthenticatedUser = GetSSOToken())
        {   
            var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();                    
                objMainWindow.Show();
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
            }));
        }
        ShowProgress = false;
    }
```

but when the code reaches to below step

```
                MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();                    
                objMainWindow.Show();
```

the log-in screen is hanging.

I need to keep the log-in screen very much active as long as mainwindow is not launched. Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: Tip: Just open the Window in the normal way, show a progressbar/loop/thingy and start loading the resources then instead of making the login window responsible for background loading.

Comment: You're not supposed to open a Window from the ViewModel... The ViewModel should never manipulate the UI directly.

Comment: Putting things on UI dispatcher doesn't put it on separate thread, it will put the delegate on UI thread instead. It will block UI thread at line `MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();`. You should try moving the time taking logic in MainWindow to other thread.

Comment: @RohitVats can u pls elaborate on this. like should I write MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow(); on a thread or write MainWindow internal code on thread.